# g++ TestCpp.cpp -pthread -std=c++11 -o test;

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I don't know how to pass the method with a lambda parameter into the std::thread.
My code sample as below:

```
using namespace std;
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>     
template<typename var>
void show(int a, var pf)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; pf(i))
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int int_test = 10;
    auto func = [](int &x)->int{ return x = x + 1; };
    show(10, func);
    std::thread a(&show, 10, func);
    a.join();
}
```

Compile with the command:
`g++ ThreadLambda.cpp -pthread  -std=c++11 -o test;`

And the error show:

```
ThreadLambda.cpp:149:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, main()::<lambda(int&)>)’
     std::thread a(&show, 10, [](int &x)->int{ return x = x + 1; });
```

Comment: #include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

template<typename var>
void show(int a, var pf)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; pf(i))
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int int_test = 10;
    auto func = [](int &x)->int{ return x = x + 1; };
    show(10, func);
    std::thread a(&show, 10, func);
    a.join();
}

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 1):

`show` is a template so you need to provide the template arguments before you can take a pointer to it:

```
std::thread a(&show<decltype(func)>, 10, func);
```

Comment: @KhanhLeVan Note that in your question you claimed that you did not know how to pass a method **with a lambda parameter** into something. It turned out that you did not know how to pass **a templated entitiy** into that something (the lambda was fine). Let that be a warning against jumping to conclusions, especially when debugging. Be wary of focusing on one thing to the point where you are blind to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void show(int N, std::function<void(int&)> pf)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; pf(i))
    {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int int_test = 10;
    auto func = [](int &x)->int{ return x = x + 1; };
    show(int_test, func);
    std::thread a(&show, int_test, func);
    a.join();
}
```

Comment: Yeah. So great. Thanks, Sergey Aleksandrovich. Easy to understand.